# How to get data on internal object of JSON?

Tags: angular

Hi i need to display information about my sessions
IMy JSON is

```
{
    "title": "Dracula",
    "localDate": "2018-05-17",
    "sessionEntityList": [
        {
          "id": 437,
          "localTime": "11:00:00"
        },
        {
           "id": 443,
           "localTime": "13:15:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 444,
            "localTime": "15:30:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 445,
            "localTime": "17:45:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 446,
            "localTime": "20:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 447,
            "localTime": "22:15:00"
        }
    ]
},
```

i trying to get my ids like

```
 <div *ngFor="let sch of schedule.sessionEntityList">
   {{sch.id}}
  </div>
```

but nothing is displaying and no error.
How can i display it?

My component is :

```
 ngOnInit() {

this.sessionService.getSchedule().subscribe(data  => {
    this.schedule = data;

   });
```

}

```
export class Schedule{
  title:string;
  localDate:string;
  sessionEntityList:Array<Ses>;
}
export class Ses{
  id : number;
  localTime:string;
}
```

mb i need to edit smth in my coponent?

Comment: Your html looks fine, sure you don't have a typo in your ts?

Comment: check your DOM whether elements are there or not?

Comment: check for any errors in console

Comment: can you `console.log(data)`

Comment: everything look good in console iw got all my JSONs

Comment: send the console result once

Comment: sometimes you may need to do `data.data`

Comment: 0
:
localDate
:
"2018-05-17"
sessionEntityList
:
Array(5)
0
:
{id: 436, localTime: "12:00:00"}
1
:
{id: 439, localTime: "14:21:00"}
2
:
{id: 440, localTime: "16:42:00"}
3
:
{id: 441, localTime: "19:03:00"}
4
:
{id: 442, localTime: "21:24:00"}
length
:
5
__proto__
:
Array(0)
title
:
"50 Shadows of Gray"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: [check it is working fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpgfqr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: try `console.log(data.sessionEntityList)`

Comment: session-list.component.ts:37 undefined

Comment: see there is no `sessionEntityList` in that `data`

Comment: can you send an image of the `console.log`, try `console.log(data.data)`

Comment: seems you are getting array, try
`console.log(data[0])`
 `this.schedule = data[0];`

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/fLvwdy) its  console.log(data.data);
        console.log(data);

Comment: there you are, shcedule is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `inputs` I saw that `schedule` is an `array`,

So, you need to loop twice, one for `schedule` and other for `sessionEntityList`

```
<div *ngFor="let schedule_data of schedule">
    <div *ngFor="let sch of schedule_data.sessionEntityList">
        {{sch.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpgfqr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**Ps:**

If you want to show only one object, change `html` to:

```
<div *ngFor="let sch of schedule[0].sessionEntityList">
    {{sch.id}}
</div>
```

Comment: its working,thanks a lot) but can i display only id's of my one "session"?

Comment: Glad to help you, you can `upvote` and `accept` my answer. If you found helpful.

Comment: @НазарЛихолатDid you check the demo? It works for all ids.

Comment: as, I donot have his object, I created a loop of same objects and displayed in demo

Comment: yea,its displaying all id's of all objects but i need to display ids of specific object. Like: Title - Drcalula , Date = 2018-17-05, IDs = 443,437...

Comment: specific means for the first one?

Comment: @НазарЛихолат, I updated answer, to show only for one object, please check

Comment: display only ids that are in specific Object

Comment: [like this you needed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpgfqr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: no mentions, glad to help you, you can upvote my answer, if you find it useful.

Comment: @НазарЛихолат, got your required solution?